# Connecting twice to same Google Earth Engine service account

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm building an internal lib for my company that rely on service accounts to reach Google Earth Engine API. The previous developer went to excessive length to make sure that the `ee.Initialize()` method was never called twice for the same account in the same session.

A simple example would be:

```py
# connect to the service account
credential_file_path = credential_folder_path / "ee-private-key.json"
credential_file_path.write_text(ee_token)
credentials = ee.ServiceAccountCredentials("", str(credential_file_path))
ee.Initialize(credentials=credentials, http_transport=httplib2.Http())

# do ee stuff 
number = ee.Number(1)
print(number.getInfo())

# connect again 
ee.Initialize(credentials=credentials, http_transport=httplib2.Http())

# do other ee stuff 
print(number.getInfo())
```

I tried locally and it ran smoothly so is it a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's no big deal if you call it twice.   Most of the library notices that it's already been initialized once and skips doing unnecessary work.